# What is the difference between the orientation and the direction of a vector?

Tags: vectors, orientation

I came across this recently, and was confused regarding the difference between the orientation and the direction of a vector. Does the orientation refer to the relative coordinate which the vector is in?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2oGkTt4HE2mdldZZ0VwTU1xb1E

Comment: Do you remember where you came across it?

Comment: Well, it is from a confusing lecture note:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2oGkTt4HE2mdldZZ0VwTU1xb1E

Answer (score 0):

Orientation pertains to the chirality of the vector. The number of dimensions with which you're working also changes your terminology a bit depending on how you would describe that chirality. Two dimensions use "clockwise" and "counter-clockwise," and three dimensions use "left-handed" and "right-handed."

Direction is a bit more simple than that. Typically, the direction of a vector pertains to the number of degrees from the x-axis (or whichever axis you decide to start with) starting at due East (or from whichever side of the axis you decide to start from). With the positive side of the x-axis as 0 degrees and the vector projecting from the origin, counter-clockwise is typically used to determine how many degrees from the x-axis the vector lies.

Comment: What is the "chirality" of a vector?

Comment: Disclaimer: This is more of a physics question.

Chirality can most easily be explained as a physical cardinality of components or vectors that makes the object or force non-super-imposable to its mirror image. This allows the orientation of the concept to change what is being represented.